# Insert into using select * then replacing a column

Tags: sql, db2

Not sure this can be done but I am trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT TOP 1 * (replace a specific date column with hard-coded value) from AnotherTable
```

What I need to do is replace one of the columns with a hard-coded date value.  I have many tables and it would take forever to do each table, as well as there are NULLS and NOT NULL's.  So I'm trying to copy the first row of the target table then change the date value that's in there.

I have no PK_ID or INT number for a unique row value so I cannot do an update.

Comment: might be easier to just do an insert  (if you have to use `*`) and then just do an update on the column and set the value.

Comment: Hi Jamie,  I don't have a PK_ID or unique identifier so that would be impossible...

Comment: what do you mean you dont have one?  In the table you're inserting into?

Comment: yes sir, unfortunately, there are no PK_ID's or anything to identify a unique record.  It's weird but I'm pulling from a source that's already dimensional (not transactional) so I don't have a unique PK_ID on the tables.  We're just doing a one-to-one load from source to target

Comment: you might need a multi step solution then.. maybe insert into temp or table variable.. update.. then insert into target

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, I think. Query would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( myFieldName )
SELECT '2015-12-07'
FROM AnotherTable
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I tried that and I think I need to copy the whole row and at the same time replace the date.  I'm getting NULL and NOT NULL errors on some of the key columns.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert a hard coded value with selected valued of another table then you have to specify column names. so the query looks like

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FieldName1,FieldName2,.... )
SELECT top 1 '2015-12-07',a.Value1,......
FROM AnotherTable a
```

Comment: I'm trying to hard-code the date mainly because I need a dummy record in there that's way past today.  It's for a Datastage job that's failing due to an insert command.  I need to insert this record with a date like '3099-12-31' way in the future so I can delete it without error.